# how to str_replace variables $name to file

Tags: php, str-replace

When I try to `str_replace` in file name is `fff.php` I cannot to print `$var` name not value to the file.

```
<?PHP
$path_to_file = 'fff.php';
$var_str = var_export($viewer, true);
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace("//","case \"13\";
$viewer =\"jjhj/jhjh/344.mp3\";  //I put value to variable 
echo $viewer ; //Here I need to print the $ and name of the variable only
break;
//",$file_contents);
file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
echo "your file is ok";
?>
```

look when I try to replace the name of variables not the value, look what happen in result -

fff.php

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
switch ($id){
case "1";
$viewer = "jhhghg/pic1.jpg";
echo $viewer ;
break ;
// my str_replace starting
    case "13";
     ="jjhj/jhjh/344.mp3";  //I put value to variable but now name empty
    echo  ; //Here I need to print the $ and name of the variable only  also here
    break;
    //
    //my str_replace end
    default;
    echo"your request error";
    }
    ?>
```

that's my problem I need only print the variable name. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget to escape the '$' sign ($viewer)? Escape them otherwise php assumes it as a variable and replaces it with it's value, which doesn't exist.

```
$file_contents = str_replace("//","case \"13\";
\$viewer =\"jjhj/jhjh/344.mp3\";  //I put value to variable 
echo \$viewer ; //Here I need to print the \$ and name of the variable only
break;
```